# jQuery- Print all results from ajax post

Tags: jquery

I am trying to setup an alert box that simply shows me all of the data returned from an ajax post. I know the post success function is working, because I can setup a simple alert to say "hi" and it will show, but in the following case, I am just getting `[object Object]'

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: domain+'/root/assets/ajax/ajax.php',
        data: $('#form-ajax').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);

        }
        });
```

And ajax.php:

```
$output = array();

$output['message'] = 'success';
$output['other-message'] = 'hello';

echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jsonFormattedResult = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a JSON object, not a string. Try `alert(data.message);`.

Comment: I know how to output each individual part of `data`, I am trying to output all of them at the same time

Comment: @JROB Then `JSON.stringify()` is what you need. See @AlexanderB's answer.